# The tensor product in the Hamiltonian of graphene

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, graphene

I have the Hamiltonian of pristine graphene
\begin{equation}
H=v_{F}.\boldsymbol{\gamma}.\boldsymbol{p}
\end{equation}
with $\boldsymbol{p}=(p_{x},p_{y})$ is the momentum operator, $v_{F}$ is the Fermi velocity and  $\boldsymbol{\gamma}=(\gamma_{x},\gamma_{y})$ given by
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{x}=\sigma_{z}\otimes\tau_{x}\otimes s_{0}, \qquad  \gamma_{y}=\sigma_{z}\otimes\tau_{y}\otimes s_{0}
\end{equation}
The unit $2\times2$ matrices $\sigma_{0}$, $\tau_{0}$ and $s_{0}$ together with the pauli matrices $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$, $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ and $\boldsymbol{s}$ act  on the valley-$1/2$, sublattice-$1/2$ and spin-$1/2$ two-dimensional subspaces of graphene, respectively.  We can be written $H$ in the matrix form
\begin{align}
&H=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & v_{F}\left(p_{x}-ip_{y}\right)  &0   &0  \\
v_{F}\left(p_{x}+ip_{y}\right)   & 0 &0 &0  \\
0 &0&0&-v_{F}\left(p_{x}-ip_{y}\right)  \\
0 &0 &-v_{F}\left(p_{x}+ip_{y}\right)  &0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
My question is that: why we have a  $4\times4$ matrix ? Normally the tensor product of the three matrix given matrix $8\times8$.

Answer (score 1):

$s_0$ is just the unit matrix. It is not explicitly written in the Hamiltonian  - every entry in the $4\times4$ matrix is a $2\times2$ unit matrix itself, but since it's just a unit matrix, a simplified notation is used.

Comment: is there the possibility of giving some explanations concerning that because I understood well and thank you so much for your answer